# DXA Java web application - profile specific properties

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

I am new to DXA, I am currently working on DXA Java web application - built on Spring 4.x & DXA 2.0 library.

We are trying to configure profile specific properties files, so that we can configure & load properties specific to environment - [Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties.)

DXA [Java Spring profiles](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-DBB2D7EB-919F-4EE3-9C15-AEF78C9D518C#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-7B8A7C7B-233D-4EB2-8781-B7CE317D7815.xml&docid=GUID-C3BDFBAE-C79E-4953-B3A8-04CF3B175F0C&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-C3BDFBAE-C79E-4953-B3A8-04CF3B175F0C) document talks about enabling profiles but doesn't talk about loading profile specific property files. I also checked InitializationUtils.loadDxaProperties to check if I can find some hint to know how to define profile specific properties, not much of help. what we are looking for is the way to load only properties specific to the environment through property files based on profile - DEV or TEST or PROD.

I even tried dxa.modules.*.properties approach, taking this approach will override properties, not load profile specific properties.